# Horizontal scrolling in Firefox to Shift+Mouse Scroll (instead of Back/Forward)

Tags: firefox, shortcut-keys

On Ubuntu 13.10, with Chrome browser, gedit, Gimp etc. the `Shift + Mouse Scroll` == `Horizontal scroll`.

With Firefox (26.0) it behaves as `Back/Forward` page, which is really annoying.

How I can disable the `Back/Forward` functionality, and change it to `horizontal scroll`?

Comment: By the way, there are some bugs in the different bugtrackers regarding this:  

1) launchpad bug for Ubuntu: https://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/firefox/+bug/1228250 ;
2) Bug in bugzilla for Mozilla Firefox: https://bugzilla.mozilla.org/show_bug.cgi?id=143038

Comment: @ruslan's answer is now the correct one

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Since Firefox 58 ([this commit](https://hg.mozilla.org/mozilla-central/rev/63b547bb4078) in particular) horizontal scrolling is the default action of Shift+Wheel, so no need to do anything special except upgrading Firefox.

Answer (score 18):

Here's how I finally got it work. I put it in very detailed form, so anyone can follow it easily.

1) Open terminal (`Ctrl`+`Alt`+`T`)

2) In terminal, run following commands:

```
sudo apt-get install xautomation
sudo apt-get install xbindkeys
```

3) Create a new file called `.xbindkeysrc.scm` to your home directory, by running in terminal

```
gedit ~/.xbindkeysrc.scm
```

4) Add the following text to the file, save it, and close the text editor:

```
; bind shift + vertical scroll to horizontal scroll events
(xbindkey '(shift "b:4") "xte 'mouseclick 6'")
(xbindkey '(shift "b:5") "xte 'mouseclick 7'")
```

5) In terminal, run command

```
xbindkeys
```

6) With Firefox browser, go to address `about:config`

7) Change following values (double click on value)

`mousewheel.with_shift.action`  to `0` (from the default `2`) 
`mousewheel.with_shift.action.override_x 1` to `1` (from the default `-1`)

8) Now `Shift+Mouse Scroll` should lead to horizontal scrolling on Firefox, instead of the default `Back`/`Forward` action.

---

Extra information:

3) `.xbindkeysrc.scm` is a hidden file (because it starts with a dot), and that's why you cannot see it with `nautilus` or other filesystem browser by default. You can hit `Ctrl+H` to see hidden files.

5) It seems, that you have to run it only once -- not at every time you log on. I also tried removing the `xbindkeys` and the horizontal scroll worked until next reboot/login.

7) If you set them as `1`, `-1`, you will get *"diagonal scroll"* when trying to scroll fast. That's why I think it is necessary to use options `0`, `1` instead of `1`, `-1`.

Comment: I'll just add that `mousewheel.with_shift.delta_multiplier_x;300` increases the horizontal speed to about the same as the vertical for me.

Comment: The unfortunate thing now is that all apps (not just Firefox) will get button6 instead of shift+button4, and therefore side-scrolling will not work for them. But I used this anyway, as I use firefox so much.

Answer (score 11):

You can **disable** the `Back/Forward` functionality, by going into `about:config` and modifying `mousewheel.with_shift.action` to `1` instead of the default `2`.

I could not find a way to enable horizontal scrolling using the mousewheel as you see in Google Chrome but the left and right arrow keys do the job. However, I came across this:

> Configure your Linux key binding to make Shift+Mouse wheel send an horizontal scroll event:
>
> Install `xbindkeys` and `xautomation`. Edit `~/.xbindkeysrc.scm` and write:
>
> ```
> ; bind shift + vertical scroll to horizontal scroll events
> (xbindkey '(shift "b:4") "xte 'mouseclick 6'")
> (xbindkey '(shift "b:5") "xte 'mouseclick 7'")
> ```
>
> Run xbindkeys

[Source](https://coderwall.com/p/xnez3g)

*Note that I have not tried the above myself!*

You may also want to look at  [[Shift + Mouse-Scroll-Wheel] Does NOT Scroll Horizontally](https://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/firefox/+bug/1228250)

Comment: The answer was partly correct, but with the help of that I got the horizontal scroll working. I will edit this answer and accept it.

Comment: Btw. I tried the "_xbindkeys_"-workaround described [here](http://splatoperator.com/2010/01/shift-scroll-horizontal-scroll-in-linux/) but it did not work. 

This working answer was found by trying quasirandomly some numbers in the values of `mousewheel.with_shift.action` and `mousewheel.with_shift.action.override_x`. I also tried this with and without `xbindkeys` and `xautomation`, and seems that `xautomation` is required to make this work. I don't have any idea **why** this works, but it works. Please, if you have a **better answer** or you can describe **why** this, edit the answer above.

Comment: @np8, here's what I did: I installed both `xbindkeys` and `xautomation` and created `~/.xbindkeysrc.scm` exactly as in the answer. I also had previously set `mousewheel.with_shift.action` to `1`. Once I saw I had horizontal scrolling working, I changed `1` to `2` and got the undesirable back/forward instead. So, IMO, a setting of `1` is necessary. I did not need to adjust `mousewheel.with_shift.action.override_x` and all these values are default.

Comment: Seems that the _peer review_ did not accept my edit. Se here's what I did to get it to work: 1) Install `xautomation` 2) Change `mousewheel.with_shift.action` to `0` and `mousewheel.with_shift.action.override_x` to `1`. (no need of `xbindkeys`)

Comment: @vasa1 may I suggest to move your comment into your answer?

Comment: Seems that my method above does not work. It is because I first installed the `xbindkeys` and after that ran and removed it, so there must have been something in the memory, which kept the thing working after the remove. I will add my own answer, as @guntbert suggested.

Comment: `mousewheel.with_shift.action=4` is already set by default in Firefox 67.0(at least) which makes horizontal scroll via shift+(vertical)mousewheel work. (=1 does not work anymore) src: https://bugzilla.mozilla.org/show_bug.cgi?id=143038

Answer (score 7):

Fortunately, there is a Firefox add-on for exactly this: https://addons.mozilla.org/en-US/firefox/addon/shift-scroll/
Works great for me in Firefox 50.1.0

Comment: I like this solution as other modify the shift + scroll behavior in all programs.

Answer (score 0):

I have no detailed explanation on why this is working and I discovered it by mistake (or just by simply testing random numbers) but for me it worked by setting `mousewheel.with_shift.action` to 4.

In my case it behaved like this:

- -1: completely disabled, scroll works vertically
- 0:  shift+scroll no longer does anything
- 1:  completely disabled, scroll works vertically
- 2:  navigates back and forward
- 3:  zoom in / zoom out, just like ctrl+scroll
- 4:  horizontal scroll only